# Improving UI of title bar

Tags: java, android

I have following title bar of my app.

[image]

These are ImageButtons in my code. How could I make the share, favorite, random and goto buttons jell with the title bar so that they similar to the Refresh and share buttons in Gmail app.

[image]

Do I need to modify the images?

Comment: There seems to be two completely different types of answers here. You should clarify if this question is about code/layout or about icon graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an actionbar that is compatible with early versions of android, check out this library: http://actionbarsherlock.com/

If you just want the images to be more android-y, you can use many of the built-in drawable resources by calling `android.R.drawable.ic_menu_manage` (for example for a settings button).  All of the drawables can be found in your android SDK installation directory here `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-17\data\res\drawable-mdpi` (assuming you installed to the default location).

One thing to note, not all of the drawables are public, which means some you may not be able to reference in your app directly.  What I've done in those cases is copy the drawable(s) from that directory to my own resource folder.

Comment: I think I will go with Sherlock action bar

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at adding menu items to the ActionBar.

Check this link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you already know how to add items to the ActionBar and then inflate it, but you just want better looking icons.

[Here's](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) a link to the official Android ActionBar icons.

Another resource that you could use are [these](http://www.androidicons.com/), which do cost a bit of money.